# protobuf.net v2.4.6 works, V3.0.29 throws "The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated"

Tags: protobuf-net

An InvalidOperationException is thrown by protobuf.net 3.0.* when programatically creating a runtimeTypeModel for a class that both inherits from classB and has a field of type classB. Protobuf.net v2.4.6 does not throw in this circumstance.

This minimal example, created in linqpad, shows the issue. Is the code doing something wrong? or is there an issue with protobuf.net 3.0 +?

```
class MyClass : AnotherClass
{
    public MyClass(AnotherClass ac) => _mem1 = ac;
    public AnotherClass _mem1;
}

class AnotherClass{}
                                                
RuntimeTypeModel MakeRTM( Type type)
{
    var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
    MetaType metaTypeOuter = model.Add(type, true);     
    Type baseType = type.BaseType;
    MetaType metaTypeInner = model.Add(baseType, true);
    metaTypeInner.AddSubType(1, type);
    
    int index = 0;
    foreach( var fld in type.GetFields() )
    {
        // model.CanSerialize freezes both metaTypes, which causes the exception at "metaTypeOuter.Add"
        if(!model.CanSerialize(fld.FieldType)) 
            model.Add(fld.FieldType, true); // not called, as model.CanSerialize returned true

        // throws invalidOperationException "The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated ..."
        metaTypeOuter.Add(++index, fld.Name);
    }            
    
    return model;
}

void Main()
{
    var mgt = new MyClass(new AnotherClass());
    var rtmi = MakeRTM(mgt.GetType());
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting scenario; it isn't intended to fail, no; I'll have to add it to my list - this is probably better as a github issue

Comment: Hi Marc, did this not warrant a GitHub issue? I can’t see one

Comment: Definitely, yes

Comment: Hi Marc, is there any news on a fix for this issue?

Comment: I simply haven't had time; ultimately this is something I do in spare time, and there are a lot of competing demands for that very limited time

Comment: Np, thanks Marc